# How to sum up the distinct Total Time of an Event ignoring duplicate overlaps in Times?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, recursive, time, standard-edition

I have the following `EventTimes` table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.EventTimes;
CREATE TABLE dbo.EventTimes
(
  EventTimeKeyId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  EventId INT NOT NULL,
  StartTime TIME NOT NULL,
  EndTime TIME NOT NULL
);
```

With the following data:

```
-- Event 1
INSERT INTO dbo.EventTimes (EventId, StartTime, EndTime)
VALUES 
  (1, '04:00:00', '14:00:00'), 
  (1, '06:00:00', '11:00:00'), 
  (1, '09:00:00', '12:00:00'), 
  (1, '13:00:00', '14:00:00'), -- Gap between this row and the next row
  (1, '02:30:00', '04:00:00'); -- Notice the half-hour on this one

-- Event 2
INSERT INTO dbo.EventTimes (EventId, StartTime, EndTime)
VALUES 
  (2, '00:00:00', '06:00:00'), -- Gap between this row and the next row
  (2, '09:00:00', '13:00:00'), 
  (2, '11:00:00', '15:00:00');
```

Notice:

- The same `Event` can have two time ranges that overlap each other. E.g. same `Event` from 4 AM to 2 PM and and also from 6 AM to 11 AM.
- There can also be gaps between the two time ranges. E.g. same `Event` from 1 PM to 2 PM and also from 2:30 PM to 4 PM.

End Goal:

I'm trying to calculate the `TotalTime` of a given `Event` ignoring the duplicate overlapping time. E.g. for the set of ranges of 9 AM to 1 PM and 11 AM to 3 PM, the distinct `TotalTime` should be 6 hours (9 AM to 3 PM). Conversely, I also don't want to count the time in the gaps between two time ranges. So for the set of ranges of 1 PM to 2 PM and 2:30 PM to 4 PM the `TotalTime` should be 2.5 hours. (Note these are just subsets of the full example above, and the final result should be the sum of all of these unique times per `Event`.)

The `TotalTime` should never exceed 24 hours, these times are all within a single day (as is the `TIME` data type).

Expected final results for the provided examples in the scripts above:

[image: Examples Final Results]

[dbfiddle.uk for reference.](https://dbfiddle.uk/oITtNMO2)

---

Other Info:

- If it's easier to work with datetimes, feel free to alter the data types from `TIME` to `DATETIME`. I can convert the results back, no problem.
- I believe some sort of recursion is needed to solve this. I feel I'm pretty close on a solution, but not quite there yet.

In a case such as 2:30 - 4:00 and 4:00 - 14:00, I'd expect the Total Time to be 11.5 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the complexity results from the overlapping intervals.

If we pack the intervals so there are no overlaps, the solution is a straightforward group and sum.

The following code uses Itzik Ben-Gan's [interval packing solution](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/new-solution-packing-intervals-problem):

> Packing intervals is a classic T-SQL problem that involves packing groups of intersecting intervals into their respective continuous intervals. I set a challenge to myself to try and find an elegant solution that can achieve the task by using only one supporting index and a single scan of the data, and I found one.

```
-- Itzik Ben-Gan's interval packing solution
-- https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/new-solution-packing-intervals-problem
WITH 
    C1 AS
    (
        SELECT 
            *,
            prvend = MAX(ET.EndTime) OVER (
                PARTITION BY ET.EventId
                ORDER BY ET.StartTime, ET.EndTime
                ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
      FROM dbo.EventTimes AS ET
    ),
    C2 AS
    (
        SELECT 
            *,
            grp = SUM(isstart) OVER (
                PARTITION BY C1.EventId
                ORDER BY C1.StartTime, C1.EndTime
                ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
        FROM C1
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            VALUES
            (
                CASE 
                    WHEN C1.StartTime <= C1.prvend 
                    THEN NULL 
                    ELSE 1 
                END
            )
        ) AS A (isstart)
    ),
    Packed AS
    (
        SELECT 
            C2.EventId, 
            StartTime = MIN(C2.StartTime), 
            EndTime = MAX(C2.EndTime)
        FROM C2
        GROUP BY 
            C2.EventId, 
            C2.grp
    )
-- Sum the packed intervals by EventId
SELECT 
    P.EventId, 
    TotalTime = SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, P.StartTime, P.EndTime)) / 60.0
FROM Packed AS P
GROUP BY 
    P.EventId;
```

| EventId | TotalTime |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11.500000 |
| 2 | 12.000000 |

The initial sort can be avoided with an index on `(EventId, StartTime, EndTime)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that uses Run Length Encoding to compress overlapping time ranges -

**SCHEMA AND DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.EventTimes;
CREATE TABLE dbo.EventTimes
(
  EventTimeKeyId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  EventId INT NOT NULL,
  StartTime TIME NOT NULL,
  EndTime TIME NOT NULL
);

-- Event 1
INSERT INTO dbo.EventTimes (EventId, StartTime, EndTime)
VALUES 
  (1, '04:00:00', '14:00:00'), 
  (1, '06:00:00', '11:00:00'), 
  (1, '09:00:00', '12:00:00'), 
  (1, '13:00:00', '14:00:00'), -- Gap between this row and the next row
  (1, '02:30:00', '04:00:00'); -- Notice the half-hour on this one

-- Event 2
INSERT INTO dbo.EventTimes (EventId, StartTime, EndTime)
VALUES 
  (2, '00:00:00', '06:00:00'), -- Gap between this row and the next row
  (2, '09:00:00', '13:00:00'), 
  (2, '11:00:00', '15:00:00');

-- Final Results expected for these 2 examples
SELECT 1 AS EventId, 11.5 AS TotalTime
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS EventId, 12 AS TotalTime;
```

| EventId | TotalTime |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11.5 |
| 2 | 12.0 |

**SOLUTION**

```
WITH x
AS
(
    SELECT EventID
         , StartTime
         , EndTime
         , IIF(
               starttime <= MAX(EndTime) OVER (PARTITION BY EventID
                                               ORDER BY StartTime
                                               ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
                                              )
               OR endtime >= MIN(starttime) OVER (PARTITION BY EventID
                                                  ORDER BY StartTime
                                                  ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
                                                 )
             , 1
             , 0) AS grp
    FROM dbo.EventTimes
)
   , j
AS
(
    SELECT EventID
         , MIN(starttime) AS stID
         , MAX(endtime) AS eID
    FROM x
    WHERE x.grp = 1
    GROUP BY x.EventID
           , x.grp
    UNION ALL
    SELECT x.EventID
         , x.starttime AS stID
         , x.endtime AS eID
    FROM x
    WHERE x.grp = 0
)
SELECT EventID
     , CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(mi, j.stID, j.eID)) AS DECIMAL(5)) / 60 AS EventTime
FROM j
GROUP BY EventID;
```

| EventID | EventTime |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11.500000 |
| 2 | 12.000000 |

[DB Fiddle for reference](https://dbfiddle.uk/-rnXeoTS)